# After making an API request from the server, how do I retrieve that from the frontend?

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am making a `GET` request to a third party API from my server.
The request returns a `JSON` response.

Now that I have that `JSON`, I want to make a fetch API request from the front end to the server in order to retrieve that `JSON` and display it on the front end.

Currently my setup is like this:

```
www.siteA.com/backend > This is a page on the backend.
It makes a request to a third party site that returns some json data
```

```
www.siteA.com/frontend > This is the front end of the site.
I make a fetch request to www.siteA.com/backend to retrieve the json data that
was returned from the backend api request to the third party site.
```

When I examine the response I get from my fetch request from www.siteA.com/frontend to www.siteA.com/backend, it is receiving literally the whole html page, whereas I only want the JSON data.

How do I retrieve the json from the front end?

Comment: You're thinking about this the wrong way round, use the fetch-api to call a page on your server, which would then call the 3rd party api and return that as it's response to the fetch-api call from your front-end

Comment: [MDN: Using Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: @TommyBs that is what I am doing. I have a js file on the front end, and i make the request to the backend page that has the api request to the third party on it.
When i console log what gets returned in the request on the front end to the backend it returns a readable stream of the whole page - html (not the data that gets returned from the request on the backend

Comment: Then the question you should really be asking is why your backend is sending the response in the wrong format. Post some of your server code so we can look at that

Comment: I am using a pre built api request asset in a CMS (Squiz Matrix), so coding is not required - i enter things like the request url. From the front end I make a request to that backend page, and the page is what gets returned. Maybe I am misunderstanding some fundamental concepts here, I am not so familiar with API requests

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to provide us more information? Are you just looking for a way to get data from an API? If yes, the easiest option in my opinion is to use the `fetch()` method

```
    fetch('www.your-restapi.com/something-here')
      .then(res=> {
        return res.json()
      })
      .then(data => {
       // your data is available 
      })
```

Comment: Hi Wesley, thanks for answering. I am using fetch to get the page from the backend, but what I want to do is only retrieve the json data that the backend has already retrieved from its own request to the third party site. I have edited my original question to try to improve it as people has voted it down